# How to enable the native edit image when capturing photo?

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

When I use the native camera to take a picture, I got this:

[image]

When I click that, it will show an edit option:

[image]
[image]

However, in my app, when I call an intent to open the camera with followed code and take a picture:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

Somehow, it does not show that edit option anymore. It only provides check and close icons:

[image]

If the native camera can open it, I believe there should be a way to set it there via the intent code.

I know that not all android phones support this. But, at least, I would like to provide that edit feature for the ones that have it.

Comment: I am not sure you will be able to get those controls via simple Intent - generally, in such native apps, there is typically exist code to check if camera activity is called from within same app or called by another app using Intent - and based on it, they show/hide these additional controls. You may need to develop a custom camera app if you want to have full control over editing/other features.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 `Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, null));`
But in reality best way is too build your own camera app wtih google camera API

Comment: I have tried it, but it only enables editing without capturing an image first.